# Using ArangoSearch, how to index data from multiple collection with custom logic?

Tags: arangodb

I'd like to use ArangoSearch to index and search data on a [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

I have a collection `products`, a collection `values` and some edges between them to find values belonging to a record. Each edge have a property `attribute` to specify which field this value is for.

Is it possible to create a view with a field configured to follow a link, applying some custom filters on it (eg. `attribute == 'description'`)?